# Unable to start mongod : version 'libssl.so.10' not found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, libssl, libcrypto

So I simply want to run mongod in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I cannot do it because the following messages appear:

```
 mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongod)
 mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongod)
```

I already followed a lot of online solutions on similar threads and I'm unable to do it.
In the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder I have symbolic links with name libssl.so.10 pointing to libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypt.so.10 pointing to libcrypto.so.1.0.0.

If you please could point me in the right direction I would be so grateful because I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I'm on an EC2 machine running on amazon, it already was installed and I had no problem at all until today.I restarted the machine and now I can start mongod.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the problem any more, the question should be closed

Comment: I met the same problem, and try to solve it. But I found that I use a error version, default is amazon* isnot ubuntu. please check, I hope can help u.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcLsz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that tried to contribute but I could not found a solution and just did a reset of the server.

If someone find the same problem and cannot do a full reset I'd love to see this question answered, for now a reset is the best answer.